# How to get all existing messages from queue & stop consumer

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to get all awaiting messages from a queue & then stop consumer. But it continues to wait for a new messages. I removed all unnecessary code:

```
public class Listener {

    private Channel channel;

    public Listener(boolean futureActionsAllowed) {
        this.futureActionsAllowed = futureActionsAllowed;
        channel = RabbitMQ.getChannel(TasksStatusOpts.QUEUE_NAME, TasksStatusOpts.DURABLE, TasksStatusOpts.EXCLUSIVE,
                TasksStatusOpts.AUTO_DELETE);
    }

    public void getAndExit() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        QueueingConsumer queueingConsumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume(TasksStatusOpts.QUEUE_NAME, TasksStatusOpts.AUTO_ACK,
                queueingConsumer);
        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = queueingConsumer.nextDelivery();
            if (delivery == null) {
                channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
                Connection conn = channel.getConnection();
                channel.close();
                conn.close();
                break;
            } else {
                String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), Charsets.UTF_8);
                handle(message, delivery.getEnvelope());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Listener(false).getAndExit();
    }

}
```

Comment: you can check if there is an API call to get the current queue count. if so, when you start the application, you can read the queue count and run your loop that many times and then stop the application. or if there is an API to get the message delivery time, you can stop the application when you start getting the messages which are delivered after the application start time

Comment: If you need to consume all messages from a queue and exit, you should not rely on the number of messages in a queue. If the consumer starts before than the produces (even for a small fraction of time), this approach will fail. If producer publishes messages with a small delay between them and consumer reads them fast enough, you will encounter a situation when producer is still working but queue is empty. So use timeouts, not message counts.

Answer (score 2):

`nextDelivery()` without arguments just waits for a message when queue is empty. It shall never return `null`. Instead you might be looking for [nextDelivery(timeout)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html#nextDelivery-long-) with a timeout. When time is out, the method will return `null`.

You may also note that this method is deprecated, see [RabbitMQ Java API Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) for a modern example.